# History API HTML5 + jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html5, html5-history-api

Не совсем могу понять как реализовать, что бы при аякс запросе, скрипт выдергивал только ту часть сайта которая отличается. Допустим у меня есть сайт с двумя страницами, если я обращаюсь к первой странице напрямую и через эту страницу подгружаю контент второй страницы, то как мне узнать что именно выдергивать из всей страницы... Если сделать изначально чтобы вторая страница была только с нужным контентом без всего, то тогда на неё нельзя будет обратиться напрямую... В общем я думаю мои вопрос понятен...дайте какой-нибудь материал по этому поводу или поясните сами, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А причем тут History API?
Допустим, вы сейчас на first.html. И у вас есть общий контент-блок для двух страниц (div#content). Вот таким запросом вы можете получить страницу second.html, взять только часть, которая содержится в div#content и заменить содержимое div#content на текущей странице (first.html). Обращаться напрямую к second.html тоже можно.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "second.html",
}).done(function( res ) {
  $("#content").html( $(res).find('#content').html() );
});
```

Comment: да решение подходит, но почему то у меня не ищет #content внутри res...существование элемента 100%, проверил всё через консоль...undefined выдает

Comment: нашел решение проблемы с выбором элемента, почему то jQuery требует что бы #content был в другом блоке, а у меня он был в body, так что обернул #content в блок #super_content и всё заработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Возвращать с сервера данные зависимо от того, какой тип запроса. Например, если AJAX, то возвращать только внутренности body, иначе ещё и оборачивать в обвязку.

JQuery добавляет заголовок:
X-Requested-With = XMLHttpRequest

Так что в серверной части вашего приложения можно проверять:

```
function isAjax (headers) {
  return headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest');
}
```